# Next.js: exportPathMap not found despite having one in next.config.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

**Error:**

`No "exportPathMap" found in "next.config.js". Generating map from "./pages"`

---

But I do have `exportPathMap` based on the [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs#static-html-export):

my `next.config.js` contains:

```js
const withCss = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules");

module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: async function(
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {
      "/": { page: "/" },
      "/menu": { page: "/menu" },
      "/about": { page: "/about" }
    };
  }
};

module.exports = withCss({
  cssModules: true
});

module.exports = withSass(
  withTM({
    transpileModules: ["react-bulma-components"],
    sassLoaderOptions: {
      includePaths: ["./components"]
    }
  })
);
```

I have also tried removing the default mappings:

```js
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: async function() {
    return {
      "/": { page: "/" },
      "/menu": { page: "/menu" },
      "/about": { page: "/about" }
    };
  }
};
```

As well as moving it inside the `withCss()` based on my research:

```js
module.exports = withCss({
  exportPathMap: async function() {
    return {
      "/": { page: "/" },
      "/menu": { page: "/menu" },
      "/about": { page: "/about" }
    };
  }
});
```

The two exports `withSass()` and `withCss()` seems to be working though,
what did I do wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

My `next.config.js` is in the root project directory, if you're by any chance wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-assigning your module.exports multiple times, so the `exportPathMap` and `withCss` get missing. The config, in this case, should look like this:

```js
module.exports = withCss(
  withSass(
    withTM({
      transpileModules: ["react-bulma-components"],
      sassLoaderOptions: {
        includePaths: ["./components"]
      },
      exportPathMap: async function(
        defaultPathMap,
        { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
      ) {
        return {
          "/": { page: "/" },
          "/menu": { page: "/menu" },
          "/about": { page: "/about" }
        };
      }
    })
  )
);
```

Comment: Huge thanks. I'm just new to this kind of export thing.

Also would like to point out that you've got some syntax errors: `statement expected`, and `unexpected token (eslint)`

Answer (score 0):

exportPathMap is currently discouraged by next.js contributors. Please have a look at https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/10983#issuecomment-611147932

Otherwise the correct answer is

```
module.exports = withCss(
  withSass(
    withTM({
      transpileModules: ["react-bulma-components"],
      sassLoaderOptions: {
        includePaths: ["./components"]
      },
      exportPathMap: async function(
        defaultPathMap,
        { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
      ) {
        return {
          "/": { page: "/" },
          "/menu": { page: "/menu" },
          "/about": { page: "/about" }
        };
      }
    })
  )
);
```

Comment: ```info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - using build directory: /app/.next
info  - Copying "static build" directory
info  - No "exportPathMap" found in "next.config.js". Generating map from "./pages"
``` i get these from default behaviour on a build - info log implying one is required - i.e. default behaviour may cause some confusion if next are looking to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

```
module.exports = withCss(withSass(
 withTM({
 transpileModules: ["react-bulma-components"],
sassLoaderOptions: {
  includePaths: ["./components"]
},
cssModules: true,
exportPathMap: async function(
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
) {
    return {
    "/": { page: "/" },
    "/menu": { page: "/menu" },
    "/about": { page: "/about" }
    };
}
})
));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!